# remove drupal admin menu from actual site

Tags: 7, theming

i'm using drupal 7 and i want to hide the admin toolbar from the normal sites. but in the configuration i can only find the option to disable the toolbar completely. what i want is that it is only visible on "mysite.com/admin/" and removed from the actual website.

i found some drupal modules with which you can collapse the toolbar or hide it by pressing the UP key but what i want the complete admin toolbar markup gone on my actual site.

i'm removing all the drupal system css and js anyway (using the template.php file) so even if i wanted the admin toolbar on my sites it would look messed up because of the missing styles and scripts.

any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can remove the toolbar from the "normal" part of you're site by unsetting its entry in the `$page` array using `hook_page_alter`. You can do this in either a module or a theme.

```
function mymodule_page_alter(&$page) {
  unset($page['page_top']['toolbar']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `admin_menu_supress()` to remove the admin menu from a specific page. It can be called from almost anywhere.

Reference - https://www.rit.edu/drupal/api/drupal/sites!all!modules!admin_menu!admin_menu.module/function/admin_menu_suppress/7.43

Answer (score 0):

The admin toolbar is only visible when you log in as admin; for the normal users, this toolbar will not be display.

Comment: Not true...any role can be granted the 'Use the administration toolbar' permission.

Comment: ok, But For the questioner don't want admin toolbar for the normal users.He needs only on /admin.Thats why i said like that.

Comment: What if his users have access to *some* parts of the admin section but not others? The downvote was perhaps a bit harsh though, I've removed it

Comment: i did indeed want to remove it for the admin as well, so that it's removed no matter which role you are.

Comment: If it so, then "Toolbar" is a module, you can go to modules and uninstall the toolbar module.

Comment: i meant for the admin role, not on the admin site. it should be there on the admin sites and it should be gone on the normal sites (for every user no matter which role)